# How can I debug an invalid POST body?

Tags: serialization, asp.net-core

I have a method in my controller whose signature looks like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Post([FromBody] MyDataType value)
```

When my frontend sends the POST data, it never even reaches this method, erroring out and returning HTTP 400 (Bad Request).  The response body says:

```
{"lastUpdated":["The supplied value is invalid."]}
```

The value of the invalid lastUpdated property being sent is:

```
"June 13, 2018, 14:05:48"
```

On my `MyDataType` class, the `LastUpdated` property is defined like so:

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(Converters.DateFormatConverter))]
public DateTime LastUpdated { get; set; }
```

And the `DateFormatConverter` is a Newtonsoft.Json serialization converter that specifies the correct format for datetime values:

```
public class DateFormatConverter : IsoDateTimeConverter
{
    public DateFormatConverter()
    {
        DateTimeFormat = "MMM' 'dd', 'yyyy', 'HH':'mm':'ss";
    }
}
```

As near as I can tell, this format matches the data being sent, and yet it's failing to validate.  Whatever's going wrong is not in any code of mine that I can place a breakpoint in, so how do I debug this and figure out what's going wrong?

Comment: Use something like [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to inspect the traffic as it goes over

Comment: The problem isn't the traffic.  Chrome Dev Tools already tells me exactly what's going on with the request and the response.  The problem is that the server is returning a 400 error without ever going into any of my code, and I don't know how to track down what the problem is so I can figure out how to fix it.

Comment: NonPropertyUnknownValueIsInvalidAccessor is the error here.

Comment: OK, and what in the world does that actually mean?  My brain throws an exception when I try to parse it...

Comment: Have you tried setuping a middleware to trap the whole stacktrace ? 
Something like:
```app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
  try
  {
    await next.Invoke();
  }
  catch(Exception e)
  {
    //have a look to e here
    throw;
  }
}); ```


If this middleware is wired before AddMvc, you'll see what actually is in the request through `context`.

Comment: Is the format supposed to contain single quotes?  The date being sent doesn't contain them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct format is `"MMMM' 'dd', 'yyyy', 'HH':'mm':'ss"`